# Postgres pg_dump copy table to another database isn't copying columns

Tags: postgresql, table, pg-dump, copy

Goal: copy a single table including all columns from one database to another using psql on the command line, avoiding an issue with XML from QGIS layer styles.

I am running the following on the command line

```
pg_dump -t table_to_copy source_db | psql target_db
```

as shown in places like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195125/copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-postgres).

The `table_to_copy` is `public.layer_styles` generated from QGIS containing layer styles.

The command seems to be copying the `table_to_copy` to the `target_db` just fine, but when I look in `table_to_copy` itself in `target_db`, there are no data, just empty columns.  The existing table from which I'm copying has 13 columns, each with 6 rows of data.

I'm getting the following error during this operation:

`ERROR:  invalid XML content
DETAIL:  line 1: StartTag: invalid element name
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
CONTEXT:  COPY layer_styles, line 1, column styleqml: "<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>`

This suggests an issue with the XML from QGIS.  I've seen some responses like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168451/restoring-public-layer-styles-table-from-postgis-dump) suggesting using SQL in pgAdmin to avoid this, but I want to do this on the command line so I can script it.  Can this be done on the command line with pg_dump, pg_restore or some other method?

I'm running Postgres 10 on macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: It looks like the destination database isn't prepared to accept that XML content. is that XML?

Comment: Yes, it is XML.  Any suggestions on how to handle that?  All solutions I've come up with are kludgy at best.